# Azure: What are the Account Name and Access Key when using the Storage Emulator?

Tags: php, azure, connection-string, azure-blob-storage

I'm following this guide:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/07/08/accessing-windows-azure-blob-storage-from-php.aspx

but with the emulators, and not with an actual Azure account.

What should I use in this line?

```
$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob('blob.core.windows.net', 
                                                         'Your_Storage_Account_Name', 
                                                         'Your_Primary_Access_Key');
```

Answer (score 6):

For the emulator, the storage account name is `devstoreaccount1`

and the key is `Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==`

This is independent of language, SDK, etc. and the SDKs typically have shortcuts for dev storage (at least the .NET SDK does). For instance, with .NET and C#, you don't need to know the details of the emulator account:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

Answer (score 3):

$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob();

from Windows Azure SDK for PHP http://phpazure.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Blob%20storage&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If no parameters are given to Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob() it will assume you want to use the emulator storage, thus:

$storageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob(); 

will do what you want.

See also a great list of tutorials at http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the .NET storage client library Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll you can actually find the built in constants that make up this "well known" account name and key:

private const string DevstoreAccountName = "devstoreaccount1";
private const string DevstoreAccountKey = "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";

"Way back when", before CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount, we used to enter this data our selves when connecting to development storage. Now Microsoft, for our convenience, have hidden that connection string also as a constant inside of the .dll.

private const string DevstoreCredentialInString = "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";